# How to stop my background div from overlapping my menu div?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, css

I have a menu on the left side of my page and the content on the rest of the page. I have a dark, textured background so I want a semi-transparent background for the leftmenu div and a semi-transparent background for the content div. However, it seems like the body div is overlapping the menu div and stacking its transparency and also making the content of the menu div transparent.

I would rather have a space between the two sections. Could someone take a look at my code and offer a suggestion?

I have some code listed below but take a look at the jsfiddle to get the full picture.

http://jsfiddle.net/5xmze/  (Note, the links should be the same color as the header)

CSS:

```
#body{
 padding-left:2px;
 width: 85%;
 position: relative;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

#leftside {
 float: left;
 width: 15%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><span id="leftside">
    <ul class="leftmenu">
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="resume.php">Resume</a></li>
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></span>
</div>
<div id="body">
Content here...
</div>
```

Here's what I'm attempting to accomplish:
[image: This is what I'm trying to accomplish]

Comment: put the menu, and the body into the same div, then float the body left as well. make sure to set a width to the body and menu, or else the body will go under the menu.

Comment: Getting closer. When I float the body left, it goes under the menu.  The left has a width of 15% and the body has a width of 85%.

Comment: you can't use exactly 15% and 85% since you have padding. try changing the body to 80% and it should work.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't think of that (obviously)! Thanks! I've added another div between the leftmenu and body to add a blank space between the two divs. Would this be the appropriate way to separate them or is there a more 'professional' way to do it?

Comment: I would just put a margin-right on the menu, or margin-left on the body :). and as you wish ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to put the menu, and the body into the same parent div, then `float:left;` the body so it shows up beside the menu.

Don't forget to set a width to both elements, because if `#body`'s width is bigger than space available on the page, it will show up under the menu.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with. I've also added another div between the leftmenu and body to add a blank space between the two divs. I made this div 15px and did not add a background to it. Turned out very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){ 
$(window).resize( function() {
var s = $("body").width();
$("body").css({ "min-width":s+"px" });
});
});
</script>
<style>
/* style.css */

body {
font-size: 1em;
background-image:url('http://i1358.photobucket.com/albums/q764/kenny_johnson5/blackorchid_zpsc8d78a87.png');
color:#FFF;
font-family:Arial;
width:85%;
margin-left:16%;
}

h1 {
 font-family:Cambria,Serif;
 color:#81E500;
 text-align:center;
}

#top{
 width: 85%;
 position: relative;
}

#body{
padding-left:90px;
width: 85%;
position: relative;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

a {
color:#81E500;
font-family:Cambria,Serif;
font-size:1.5em;
}

#leftside {
 float: left;
 width: 15%;
 height: 100%;
    margin-left:-15%;
    z-index:999;
}

ul.leftmenu {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0px;
 padding:1px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 border: 1px solid;
 border-color:#000;
 height:100%;
}

li.leftmenu {
padding:5px;

}
</style>
<html>

<div><div id="leftside">
    <ul class="leftmenu">
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="resume.php">Resume</a></li>
        <li class="leftmenu"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</div>



<div id="body">
<div id="top">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt erat sit amet dolor imperdiet dignissim. Nunc eu enim erat. Suspendisse commodo faucibus risus at facilisis. Phasellus tortor urna, fringilla sed blandit non, porta vel enim. Vivamus placerat, risus et molestie elementum, risus elit dignissim elit, non porttitor nisl tortor sed lorem. Maecenas scelerisque mattis massa, vel blandit erat blandit sed. Vivamus erat augue, varius ac aliquet non, commodo id massa. Maecenas sit amet est posuere turpis ultrices aliquam. Nulla feugiat ultrices diam vitae egestas. Phasellus risus augue, dapibus nec condimentum non, tempus eu massa. Etiam sodales sodales dolor eu convallis.
</p>
<p>
Aenean in dignissim metus. Suspendisse placerat pharetra justo, et tristique neque vestibulum non. Quisque malesuada scelerisque diam eget suscipit. Donec non sollicitudin justo. Etiam sit amet massa felis. Maecenas aliquet cursus tristique. Etiam sollicitudin augue in risus venenatis rhoncus. Pellentesque tellus diam, porttitor in dapibus eu, rutrum eu lectus. Vestibulum luctus hendrerit augue vitae interdum. Donec in turpis malesuada arcu tempor placerat. Aliquam eget nisl ipsum. Cras blandit elementum vulputate. Ut vulputate ullamcorper urna, quis congue mauris laoreet nec. Morbi vitae dui eros.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus rhoncus ultrices sem et dictum. Ut ut nisl eget eros porttitor commodo auctor vitae leo. Quisque sed nulla augue, vel venenatis augue. Pellentesque bibendum sodales lectus, quis malesuada risus consectetur a. Aliquam lobortis aliquet vulputate. Duis sed velit est, in venenatis est. Vivamus viverra lacinia sapien non sodales. Aenean eleifend quam diam, id gravida tellus. Praesent dui sem, volutpat eu blandit in, volutpat ornare nulla. Nunc sed eros dolor.
</p>
<p>
Quisque sit amet diam nisl, volutpat interdum arcu. Proin et justo lorem. Mauris vitae egestas lacus. Nullam ut laoreet turpis. Donec eget metus enim, id porta orci. Nam condimentum feugiat tempor. Nunc ultricies pellentesque euismod. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam fringilla bibendum sapien, eu vestibulum nisi imperdiet tempus. Duis tincidunt magna id sapien porta vel aliquam massa tincidunt. Maecenas ut metus id augue congue scelerisque id nec enim. Ut ac nibh est, et laoreet orci. Nulla fermentum laoreet augue, in vulputate risus varius vel. Sed ac nunc quis tortor scelerisque rutrum.
</p>
<p>
Nullam adipiscing ultricies lacus ac pretium. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam convallis libero non augue sollicitudin mattis. Nunc commodo pharetra magna, tempor sagittis sem vehicula nec. Quisque massa ligula, gravida nec fringilla quis, tempus vel dolor. Nam et sem bibendum mi consectetur tincidunt. Nam placerat venenatis odio sit amet imperdiet. Integer luctus quam quis quam lobortis aliquam. Cras dignissim semper erat, ac laoreet leo volutpat quis. </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That has jQuery code in it. I'd rather not use jQuery for one little thing like this. If I was planning on using jQuery for other features on the site then I wouldn't care. However, I'm just looking for a clean, simple CSS solution to this. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: man jquery is only to maintain width on resize as you have given body width of 85% which is in percentage unit so on resizing the width of body will vary. so, to prevent it from this i added jquery!